# python multiproccesing and thread safety in shared objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-multiprocessing

I am a bit uncertain regarding thread safety and multiprocessing.

From what I can tell multiprocessing.Pool.map pickles the calling function or object but leaves members passed by references intact.

This seems like it could be beneficial since it saves memory but I haven't found any information about the thread safety in those objects.

In my case I am trying to read numpy data from disk, however, I want to be able to modify the source with out changing the implementation so I've broken out the reading part to its own classes.

I roughly have the following situation:

```py
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

class NpReader():
    def read_row(self, row_index):
        pass

class NpReaderSingleFile(NpReader):
    def read_row(self, row_index):
        return np.load(self._filename_from_row(row_index))

    def _filename_from_row(self, row_index):
        return Path(row_index).with_suffix('.npy')

class NpReaderBatch(NpReader):
    def __init__(self, batch_file, mmap_mode=None):
        self.batch = np.load(batch_file, mmap_mode=mmap_mode)

    def read_row(self, row_index):
        read_index = row_index
        return self.batch[read_index]

class ProcessRow():
    def __init__(self, reader):
        self.reader = reader

     def __call__(self, row_index):
         return reader.read_row(row_index).shape

readers = [
    NpReaderSingleFile(),
    NpReaderBatch('batch.npy'),
    NpReaderBatch('batch.npy', mmap_mode='r')
]

res = []
for reader in readers:
    with Pool(12) as mp:
        res.append(mp.map(ProcessRow(reader), range(100000))
```

It seems to me that there are alot of things that could go wrong here but I, unfortunately does not have the knowledge to determine what of test for it.

Are there any obvious problems with the above approach?

Some things that occurred to me are:

1. np.load (it seems to work well for small single files, but can I test it to see that it is safe?
2. Is NpReaderBatch safe or can read_index be modified at the same time by different processes?

Comment: You don't share objects in your code. Each process has a copy of the main process' memory. Unless you explicitely use one of the shared primitives: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes Whether this code is safe depends purely on numpy.

Comment: nice, but does that mean the numpy objects will be copied for each process? they might be very large..

Comment: There is this thing called [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write). Each subprocess will only copy the data it is going to modify. So that depends on your code. Note that it is hard to tell whether your data gets modified or not, especially with Python. There are implicit modifications under the hood, like reference counting. So you may think "I only read this variable", but in fact you modify it. However numpy lives outside Python, so I'm not sure. I guess you should measure.

Comment: Ok, thats very interesting, thanks!

Comment: @freakish I can now confirm that np.load eats up additional memory for each process, so using multiprocessing with np.load is not a viable option